# Can't get included CSS and JS files to be compressed

Tags: apache-2.2, .htaccess, compression, gzip, mod-deflate

I have enabled compression via .htaccess and in httpd.conf

However when I run it through the various online testers, its always saying that various included files are not compressed. Apache version is 2.2.15

.htaccess currently looks like this:

```
    ## EXPIRES CACHING ##

ExpiresActive On
ExpiresByType image/jpg "access 1 year"
ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access 1 year"
ExpiresByType image/gif "access 1 year"
ExpiresByType image/png "access 1 year"
ExpiresByType text/css "access 1 month"
ExpiresByType application/pdf "access 1 month"
ExpiresByType application/x-shockwave-flash "access 1 month"
ExpiresByType image/x-icon "access 1 year"
ExpiresByType application/javascript "access 2 days"
ExpiresByType application/x-javascript "access 2 days"
ExpiresByType text/javascript "access 1 month"
ExpiresByType text/x-javascript "access 2 days"
ExpiresDefault "access 2 days"


## TYPES FIX
AddType text/css .css
AddType text/javascript .js

## COMPRESS FILES ## 
SetOutputFilter DEFLATE
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/plain
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/css
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/javascript
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/x-javascript
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/xhtml+xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/rss+xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/javascript
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-javascript
BrowserMatch ^Mozilla/4 gzip-only-text/html
BrowserMatch ^Mozilla/4\.0[678] no-gzip
BrowserMatch \bMSIE !no-gzip !gzip-only-text/html
BrowserMatch \bMSI[E] !no-gzip !gzip-only-text/html
SetEnvIfNoCase Request_URI \.(?:gif|jpe?g|png)$ no-gzip
Header append Vary User-Agent env=!dont-vary 


#Remove ETags
FileETag none


# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond /home/sites/mydomain.info/public_html/wp-content/sitemaps%{REQUEST_URI} -f
RewriteRule \.xml(\.gz)?$ /wp-content/sitemaps%{REQUEST_URI} [L]

RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

httpd.conf includes this:

```
#
# Deflate output configuration
# 
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html text/plain text/xml text/css
BrowserMatch ^Mozilla/4 gzip-only-text/html
BrowserMatch ^Mozilla/4\.0[678] no-gzip
BrowserMatch \bMSIE !no-gzip !gzip-only-text/html
```

Can't find anything online that species that this wouldn't work with included files, obviously I am going wrong somewhere so any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to add cache control:

```
# CACHE-CONTROL HEADERS
<FilesMatch "\\.(ico|jpe?g|png|gif|swf|gz|ttf)$">
Header set Cache-Control "max-age=2797200, public"
</FilesMatch>
<FilesMatch "\\.(css)$">
Header set Cache-Control "max-age=2797200, public"
</FilesMatch>
<FilesMatch "\\.(js)$">
Header set Cache-Control "max-age=2797200, private"
</FilesMatch>
<filesMatch "\\.(html|htm)$">
Header set Cache-Control "max-age=86400, public"
</filesMatch>
# Disable caching for scripts and other dynamic files
<FilesMatch "\.(pl|php|cgi|spl|scgi|fcgi)$">
FileETag None
Header unset ETag
Header set Cache-Control "max-age=0, no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate"
Header set Pragma "no-cache"
Header set Expires "Sat, 2 Aug 1980 15:15:00 GMT"
</FilesMatch>
```

and set your compression level

```
# MOD_DEFLATE COMPRESSION
SetOutputFilter DEFLATE
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html text/plain text/xml application/xml application/xhtml+xml text/javascript text/css application/x-javascript application/x-httpd-php
DeflateCompressionLevel 9
```